# Google Ads Conversion & Remarketing Tag not working because tag failed to fire - status 400 - Woocommerce - Tag Manager

Tags: woocommerce, google-tag-manager, google-ads-api, google-ads-script, conversion-tracking

First of all, thanks for any help I can get here. I am not a professional and now, unfortunately, after many hours I just can't get any further.

I run a Woocommerce webshop and have integrated GA4 and Google Adwords Conversion + Remarketing via Tag Manager. In preview mode all tags and data layers are loaded correctly. But the Goolge Ads Remarketing Tag and the Conversion Tag are marked red and loaded but not sent.

The Error Message in Tag Manager Browser Plugin:  **HTTP response code indicates tag failed to fire: Status 400:**

[Google Tag Assistant - Conversion failed to fire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjQOq.jpg)

The Code in GTM Preview Mode when Remarketing Tag is fired ( everythings looks good ):

[GTM - Preview - Remarketing Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpylv.jpg)

If i open Dev Tool on my Browser i see that some google Scripts are red ( Url = googleads.g.doublecklick...... ):

[Google ads url is blocked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDYUL.jpg)

Unfortunately no conversions are recorded in Adwords and the imported conversions from GA4 are also counted only to a small amount. With the old Analytics UA I had no problems and almost all the conversions were displayed in Adwords.

GTM is published and i have no Ad Blockers running.

Conversion ID and Label is checked

The Google Ads Campaigns are running

I turned off the GTM plugin for wordpress and tried a paid plugin for google ads conversion tracking. Unfortunately i have had the same error.

In addition, I turned of almost all plugins and tested whether anything blocks. Unfortunately without result.

If I change the conversion ID in the remarketing tag and add "AW-", the tag is no longer displayed as red. However, I can not change the conversion tag because only numbers are allowed:

[Trying Conversion ID with "AW-" in Remarketing Tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNENX.jpg)

I'm realy a bit desperate and really grateful for any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Julio, we solved our problem with HTTP response code indicates tag failed to fire: Status 400. In our case, the problem was that our store was flagged as non-compliant
with the EU User Consent Policy. This caused conversions to be blocked. Try the following link: https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/11576040?hl=en There is an email address. Brief description of the problem. Send the website address and Google Ads account ID. Our conversions were unlocked after 48 hours of correcting the privacy policy and positive verification by Google of compliance with the EU User Consent Policy. I hope you can solve the conversion problem. Regards